# Call and execute rails method only on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onclick, addeventlistener

**javascript function:**

```
document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    <% execution.pause %>
});
```

**pause button:**

```
<%= button_tag(id:'pause', class: "btn btn-raised btn-primary") do %>
    <span><i class="far fa-pause-circle"></i> Pause</span>
<% end %>
```

I have this javascript function that listens when my pause button is clicked. It doesn't work properly because the line that calls `<% execution.pause %>` is executed whenever I load the page.

I know it's because I can't quite call this rails method like this. But also, I'm new with rails and I don't know how to call and execute it only on click. Please, give some suggestions.

Comment: Are you using jquery in your project?

Comment: `<% execution.pause %>` this won't work, probably you should use ajax call for it.

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery. And, how can I call it with ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= button_tag(id: 'pause', class: "btn btn-raised btn-primary") do %>
  <span><i class="far fa-pause-circle"></i> Pause</span>
<% end %>
```

Make a route to pasue  execution

```
get '/execute/pause', to "custom#pause_execution"
```

On click fire a ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#pause').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var execute_id = "<%=execution.id%>"
    // ajax request 
    $.ajax({
      url: "/execute/pause",
      type: "GET",
      data : {
        id: execute_id
      },
      dataType: "script",
    });    
  });
</script>
```

In custom_controller.rb

```
class CustomController < ApplicationController
  def pause_execution
    #assuming Execution is a model which has a pause method
    execution = Execution.find(params[:id])
    if execution.pause
       flash[:notice] = "Paused successfully!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note : - this is a sample answer modify it with your real data, model, and routes.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NataliBrito Great to know that, also am hoping that you will go ahead with this much of hint. in case if you need any further guidance please let me know.